# How to find 2nd least significant bit number and so on given and integer?

Tags: python

Given i = 1564 or 1111564

I want to find  4,6,5

least_significant_bit = 4

2nd least_significant_bit = 6

third least_significant_bit = 5

How do I do that?

Comment: You mean "digit", not "bit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

least_significant = (i % 10) / 1 = 4

second_least_significant = (i % 100) / 10 = 64 / 10 = 6

third_least_significant = (i % 1000) / 100 = 564 / 100 = 5

you can clearly notice a sequence here.
if you want to get n'th significant number of i,

```
n'th significant number = (i % 10^n) / 10^(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do in python is to convert it to string

```
i = 1564

i_str = str(i)

least_significant_bit = i_str[-1]
second_least_significant_bit = i_str[-2]
third_least_significant_bit = i_str[-3]
```

OR

Divide by 10 and get the remainder